# Search multiple strings in a excel workbook

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string, search

I am trying to design a macro to search for multiple strings in an excel.

I have the following code which searches for the word "techno" in an excel but, I need to include a variable into the code so that I can search for multiple words such "Techno", "electromagnetic", "waves", etc. at once.  I am unable to create a loop for this condition.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem? The below code works fine but, only a tweak is required to include **multiple strings** in the search.

```
Sub SearchFolders()
    Dim xFso As Object
    Dim xFld As Object
    Dim xStrSearch As String
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xStrFile As String
    Dim xOut As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xWk As Worksheet
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim xFound As Range
    Dim xStrAddress As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xUpdate As Boolean
    Dim xCount As Long

    myArray = Array("techno", "magnetic", "laser", "trent") 
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a forlder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xOut = Worksheets.Add
    For myCounter = 0 To UBound(myArray)         
        MsgBox myCounter & " is the Count No."   
        xStrSearch = myArray(myCounter)          
        MsgBox xStrSearch & " is the Value fr String search" 
        xRow = 1
        With xOut
            .Cells(xRow, 1) = "Workbook"
            .Cells(xRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
            .Cells(xRow, 3) = "Cell"
            .Cells(xRow, 4) = "Text in Cell"
            Set xFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set xFld = xFso.GetFolder(xStrPath)
            xStrFile = Dir(xStrPath & "*.xls*")
            Do While xStrFile <> ""
                Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xStrPath & "\" & xStrFile, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)
                For Each xWk In xWb.Worksheets
                    Set xFound = xWk.UsedRange.Find(xStrSearch)
                    MsgBox xFound & " is the strings found"
                    If Not xFound Is Nothing Then
                        xStrAddress = xFound.Address
                    End If
                    Do
                        If xFound Is Nothing Then
                            Exit Do
                        Else
                            xCount = xCount + 1
                            MsgBox xCount & " is the count of strings"
                            xRow = xRow + 1
                            .Cells(xRow, 1) = xWb.Name
                            .Cells(xRow, 2) = xWk.Name
                            .Cells(xRow, 3) = xFound.Address
                            .Cells(xRow, 4) = xFound.Value
                        End If
                        Set xFound = xWk.Cells.FindNext(After:=xFound)
                        MsgBox xFound & " next string" 
                        MsgBox xStrAddress & " is the address " 
                        MsgBox xFound.Address & " is the address found"
                    Loop While xStrAddress <> xFound.Address 'To check how xStrAddress is populated or do we need to declare it as a help from excel pointed out
                    myCounter = myCounter + 1
                Next
                xWb.Close (False)
                xStrFile = Dir
            Loop
            .Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    Next myCounter                           
    MsgBox xCount & "cells have been found", , 
    ExitHandler:
    Set xOut = Nothing
    Set xWk = Nothing
    Set xWb = Nothing
    Set xFld = Nothing
    Set xFso = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate
    Exit Sub
    ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the strings you are searching will always be the same, hard code them into an array and Loop through the array elements to search each string, like so:

```
Dim myArray as Variant
Dim myCounter as Long

myArray = Array("techno", "electromagnetic", ...etc.)

For myCounter = 0 To UBound(myArray)
    ... 'your code here
   xStrSearch = myArray(myCounter)
    ... 'the rest if your code here
Next myCounter
```

Comment: Hi @samuel -  I tried placing the array as suggested above. I had to update myArray to be a Variant for this to run. But, I am unable to run it for multiple iterations as the value in myCounter is not updating and I am getting an error. Even If I am able to run the counter correctly, it is failing to search for all values as per the array. Any reason for that to happen ? I can share the code here if you can help

Comment: Hi @Shan, you'd be best to ask a new question or update your existing question with the new details, but I'll keep an eye out for it in the next few minutes and see what I can do to help.

Comment: Hi @Samuel Everson: I have updated the code in the question.

Comment: Thanks @Samuel I fixed my code. Thanks for your inputs !!